# Date Range Loop in asp.net, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do i loop through between two date Ranges in C# ?

For Example-

I am creating a credit card EMI Module, Suppose one user wants to 6 EMI
I have a date range of : `"08/02/2009-08/08/2009"` I need to loop through each month

input :

```
Start Date- 08/02/2008
End Date - 08/07/2009

Charge Cycle - 6
```

Output will be like -

```
08/02/2008
08/03/2008
08/04/2008
08/05/2008
08/06/2008
08/07/2008
```

Comment: If you mean to imply that you have a date range in string format, your first step will be to convert it to a proper DateTime. The rest should follow easily from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DateTime.AddMonths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx) in a while loop like

```
DateTime dtStart = new DateTime(2009,2,8);
DateTime dtEnd = new DateTime(2009,8,8);
while (dtStart < dtEnd)
{

    Console.WriteLine(dtStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    dtStart = dtStart.AddMonths(1);
}
```

Ouput would be:

```
08/02/2009
08/03/2009
08/04/2009
08/05/2009
08/06/2009
08/07/2009
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    start = start.AddMonth(i);
    Console.WriteLine("{0:dd/MM/yy}", start);

}
```

Or if you wish:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetMonths(DateTime start, int numberOfMonths);
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfMonths; i++)
    {
        start = start.AddMonth(i); 
        yield return start;
    }
}

foreach(var date in GetMonths(DateTime.Now, 6)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0:dd/MM/yy}", date);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AddMonths() Method of Datetime.
Take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DateTime.AddMonths()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx) method.

> Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of months to the
>   value of this instance.

Like;

```
DateTime a = new DateTime(2009, 2, 8);
DateTime b = new DateTime(2009, 8, 8);

while ( a < b )
{
     Console.WriteLine(a.ToShortDateString());
     a = a.AddMonths(1);
}
```

Result will be;

```
08.02.2009
08.03.2009
08.04.2009
08.05.2009
08.06.2009
08.07.2009
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/O4bD4E).

Answer (score 0):

the below will return a list of dates between the specified dates

```
        var startDate = DateTime.Parse("08/02/2009");
        var endDate = DateTime.Parse("08/08/2009");
        var resutl = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + ((endDate.Year - startDate.Year) * 12) +  endDate.Month -1 - startDate.Month  )
            .Select(startDate.AddMonths)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: This fails for even the date range in your example, because it doesn't account for the year.